# The delegate error

Tags: objective-c, delegates, cs193p

The thing I want to do is:

First, the `TopPlacesViewController` has a segue to the class `SinglePlacePhotosViewController` (a `TableView` controller).

I create a delegate in the `TopPlacesViewController` class, then use the `prepareforSegue` method to set the `SinglePlacePhotosViewController` as the delegate and implement the protocol method.

Then when I click a photo in the `TopPlacesViewController` (TableView controller), it calls the method `TopPlacesViewController` which should show some photos from that place.

But I kept getting this error:

> [SinglePlacePhotosViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc94cc20

My `TopPlacesViewController.h` file:

```
@class TopPlacesViewController;  

@protocol TopPlacesViewControllerDelegate    
- (void)topPlacesViewControllerDelegate:(TopPlacesViewController *)sender
                            showPhotos:(NSArray *)photo;   
@end

@interface TopPlacesViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) id <TopPlacesViewControllerDelegate> delegate;   
@end
```

`TopPlacesViewController.m`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{                                                                                  
    NSDictionary *place = [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
    self.singlePlacePhotos = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:place maxResults:50];   
    [self.delegate topPlacesViewControllerDelegate:self showPhotos:self.singlePlacePhotos];  
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Flickr Photos" sender:self];   
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Flickr Photos"]) {                                  
          [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];     
    }         
}
```

Then in this I implement the delegate:

```
@interface SinglePlacePhotosViewController () <"TopPlacesViewControllerDelegate">    
- (void)topPlacesViewControllerDelegate:(TopPlacesViewController *)sender showPhoto:(NSArray *)photo    
{    
    self.photos = photo;    
}
```

Comment: segue.destinationViewController's definition doesn't have -setDelegate.

Comment: actually it has i just looked it up.

Comment: That's strange. Does `SinglePlacePhotosViewController` have it defined?

Comment: Yeah, can you show more @interface code for `SinglePlacePhotosViewController`? It looks like that is missing a @property for your delegate.

Comment: i already set the @property for the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exactly the error is obvious because you are calling the setter method (setDelegate:) of SinglePlacePhotosviewController but the @property (nonatomic,weak) id  delegate; is in TopPlacesViewController.

you are using protocol here in wrong way.
if u want pass the array of photos from TopPlacesViewController to SinglePlacePhotosviewController,
 simply assign the array from TopPlacesViewController to the array of SinglePlacePhotosviewController in prepareSegue method.

Protocols generally used for passing the reference of one class to another class, here u already have the instance of SinglePlacePhotosviewController (segue.destinationController) in TopPlacesViewController. If u want the reference of TopPlacesViewController in SinglePlacePhotosviewController then u have to make protocol in SinglePlacePhotosviewController and pass the self of TopPlacesViewController to the delegate protocol  of SinglePlacePhotosviewController in prepare segue method as u r doing here.
hope i have cleared your query, please let me know.

Comment: sorry for my late replay. Yeah, i got what you said. I know i can just use the segue.destinationController to get the reference to the singleplacePhotoViewController, but i just want to try the delegate to get this reference. So, i change the prepareforsegue like this:[segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:segue.destinationViewController]; However, it still didn't work. Could you tell why? Thank you very much.

Comment: hello Pan,firstly you are using setDelegate method which doesn't belong to your destinationController thats why u are getting error"[SinglePlacePhotosViewController setDelegate:]:unrecognized selector".yes you can do this by delegate method for which you have to declare this TopPlacesViewControllerDelegate protocol in SinglePlacePhotosViewController rather declaring it in TopPlacesViewController.try this it will help you.actually setDelegate means you are calling setter method of some   property named "delegate" which is declared in SinglePlacePhotosViewController.

Comment: ah, finally i see my problem. Thank u very much.

Comment: I just found i made a stupid mistake. lol And yeah, it helps. Thanks